# Data points collected by GPS on Arc 1960 UTM 37S do not correlate when projected on Google Earth

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, google-earth

The following points were collected using a handheld GPS Garmin 76 set to Arc 1960 UTM UPS zone 37.

```
Beacon, easting, northing
FD8,274179,9135718
FD9,277586,9136635
FD10,282122,9137245
```

On entering the points into Google Earth using the easting and northing data, the points come out to approximately 300-350m north and 55-70m west of where they should be.

When I convert the points to WGS 84 before loading (and changing the setting on Google Earth), I have the same result.

Is this a projection issue?

Is it possible that the GPS were set on a different projection to what was recorded?

Here is a GE image of the differential: the green pins are what the gps data shows and the yellow pins are where they should be.

[image: Points difference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to project data to WGS 84 datum. Use QGIS for this (open source and easy to use), you can also use ArcGIS or other tool.

Add data (in this case I used coords given as CSV file):

[image]

Go to layer properties and set projection:
[image]

It'll be something like this:
[image]

Save it as .kml (or other file format):
[image]

Open it in Google Earth:
[image]

Comment: Hey Aldo, thank you very much! This has really helped, I'm not sure where I went wrong as I did use QGIS and brought the points in as Arc 1960. However it looks all square now.